# How to test values which retrieve from db in jhipster

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jhipster

I am new to jhipster. I am trying to implement a test method to test values which are retrieved from mysql db. When I am trying to execute "gradlew test" command it will fail the relevant test case by saying "java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.[0].id". And I have added H2 Console db table values manually. My test method as follows.

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void getAllPlayersNS() throws Exception {
    // Get all the playersNList
    restPlayersNMockMvc.perform(get("/api/players-ns?sort=id,asce"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[0].id").value(1));
}
```

Where I went wrong?

Comment: You need more information than this in your question.  And please don't paste images, even worse illegible images, into your question.  Use well formatted, well thought out text instead.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited @Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the integration tests in JHipster use H2 in memory so the changes you made using H2 console are probably not used by these tests and so our table is empty (this is what your failed assertion means) because they were stored in H2 on disk in `target/h2db` folder (if you chose this option at project generation).

So either, your test should create players using PlayerNSRepository or you should add a [Liquibase migration that loads them from CSV](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/load_data.html) (look at users.csv) and restrict it to H2 db and maybe using test Liquibase context.

Comment: How add a Liquibase migration that loads them from CSV?

Comment: Could you precise your question? This is documented by Liquibase http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/load_data.html and JHipster has examples for users.csv